# Try, catch : doing something if the TRY completed successfully

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I am looping through a list of samaccountnames and performing several actions:

```
# Disabling user
try {    
    Disable-QADUser $user | Out-Null
} catch [exception] {
    "Disable-QADuser: " + $($_.Exception.Message) | out-file $logfile -append
    write-host " - Error disabling useraccount." -fore yellow
}

# Set informative description
try {    
    Set-QADuser $user -Description "Disabled $now"  | Out-Null
} catch [exception] {
    "Set-QADuser: " + $($_.Exception.Message)| out-file $logfile -append
    write-host " - Error setting informative description in AD." -fore yellow
}
```

But how do I output something if the command completed successfully? Something like

```
write-host "User $user disabled"
"User $user disabled" | out-file $logfile -append
```

All help/pointers are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I noticed that I can use `tee-object` to send the output to file as well as console.. This way I do not have to have to lines to "tee" the output:)

Comment: Well you could simply set a variable to true directly after all the statements in the try clause. An exception would skip that hence it would not be set (or remain false if you set it before the `try` when you exit the `try` and `catch` clauses. Then test for its value and perform some action accordingly.

Comment: Great tip, but not what I am after:) I vote your response up since I am sure I will have use for it later!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's anything like java, you'd just place it underneath the line you are trying to execute:

```
try {    
    Set-QADuser $user -Description "Disabled $now"  | Out-Null
    write-host "User $user disabled"
    "User $user disabled" | out-file $logfile -append
} catch [exception] {
    "Set-QADuser: " + $($_.Exception.Message)| out-file $logfile -append
    write-host " - Error setting informative description in AD." -fore yellow
}
```

Comment: +1 That's how I would do it. I don't know power-shell (yet) either :)

Comment: Ahh, so the TRY jumps to CATCH if an exception occurs?! Of course! Works great:)

Comment: It does, it's a behaviour in most (all?) languages that implement try-catch clauses.

Comment: I didn't know it either that `try` jumps to `catch` if an exception occurs! Great tip! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to keep in mind: if for some reason disabling the user didn't work, your catch block WILL NOT invoke since the error is not a terminating error. To change the type of the error to terminating error, use the ErrorAction parameter:

```
Set-QADuser $user -Description "Disabled $now" -ErrorAction Stop | ...
```

Comment: If you want to invoke something after a try-catch clause, you would use the `finally` operator.